# Weighted Job Scheduler - Retrieve Job Details

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and want to created a weighted job scheduler.
The max profit is working fine. But I need to be able to get the JobIDs associated with it so I am trying to save it in an array `jobsId`, similar to this implementation in C++: https://onlinegdb.com/a9wx3nHoN.

But then in this snippet, I am getting an error: `Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2`

```
if (profitSum > dp[i-1]) {
   dp[i] = profitSum; 
   jobsId[i,0] = jobsId[task]; // Problem is here
   jobsId[i].Append(jobs[i].id).ToArray(); //And here
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help, thanks!

Codes can be accessed here:
https://rextester.com/NXM85235

Alternatively, here is my entire snippet:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public int JobScheduling(int[] startTime, int[] endTime, int[] profit) {
        var jobs = startTime
            .Select((_, i) => new   // create custom obj
            {
                id = i,
                s = startTime[i],
                e = endTime[i],
                p = profit[i],
            }
            )
            .OrderBy(x => x.e)      // sort by end-time
            .ToArray();

        int[] dp = new int[jobs.Length];
        int [,] jobsId = new int[,] {{jobs[0].id}};
        
        int profitSum = jobs[0].p;
        int task = -1;
        dp[0] = jobs[0].p;

        for (var i = 1; i < jobs.Length; i++) {
          for (var j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (jobs[j].e <= jobs[i].s) {
              task = j;
              break;
            }
          }

          if (task != -1) {
            profitSum += dp[task];
          }

            
          if (profitSum > dp[i-1]) {
            dp[i] = profitSum; 
            jobsId[i,0] = jobsId[task]; // Problem is here
            jobsId[i].Append(jobs[i].id).ToArray();
          }
        }
        
        // Need to implement this
        for (var iter = 0; iter < jobsId.Length; iter++) {
            Console.WriteLine(jobsId[iter,0]);            
        }
            
        return dp[jobs.Length-1];
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] startTime = { 1,3,6,2 };
        int[] endTime = { 2,5,7,8 };
        int[] profit = { 50,20,100,200 };

        // Creating object
        Program job = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine(job.JobScheduling(startTime, endTime, profit));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int [,] jobsId = new int[,] {{jobs[0].id}};
```

The multi-dimensional 3d array that you are using has a fixed size .i.e. only **one**. You can't add any more elements to that array. Instead, try using List< List < int > >.

```
jobsId[i,0] = jobsId[task]; // problem here
```

Here jobsId is a 2d-array. You can't access the individual rows. You can only access elements within. For this too you need to create an array of array .i.e List< List < int > >.

And I could not figure out why are trying to get an array here.

```
jobsId[i].Append(jobs[i].id).ToArray();
```